# Unable to write to disk but disk isn't full

Tags: filesystem, files, disk

I can't write to any file, even as root, or do any other operation that requires writing. Neither can any process that needs to write, so they're all failing. `df` says I've got plenty of room:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       30G   14G   15G  48% /
udev            984M  4.0K  984M   1% /dev
tmpfs           399M  668K  399M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            997M     0  997M   0% /run/shm
```

All of the results I find for "can't write to disk" are about legitimately full disks. I don't even know where to start here. The problem appeared out of nowhere this morning.

PHP's last log entry is "failed: No space left on device (28)". Vim says "Unable to open (file) for writing". Other applications give similar errors.

After deleting ~1gb just to be sure, the problem remains. I've also rebooted. Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: @mchid it depends on the application. PHP fails with "failed: No space left on device (28)". Trying to write a file with vim says "unable to open swap file, writing impossible", then "can't open file for writing".

Comment: are you using btrfs or something?

Comment: @mchid I don't even know what that is, sorry. This is a VPS, not a machine I have physical access to.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo lsof -nP +L1`

Comment: It turned out that I was out of inodes even though I wasn't out of disk space. Problem was answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/731519/unable-to-write-to-disk-but-disk-isnt-full

Comment: You should write an answer. Give me a ping for an upvote.

Comment: And add the output of `df -i` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/689774/3) by [OP](https://askubuntu.com/users/287065/felwithe):

> Edit: It turned out that I was out of inodes even though I wasn't out of disk space. [Problem was solved here](https://serverfault.com/questions/731519/unable-to-write-to-disk-but-disk-isnt-full):
>
> ```
> You are out of inodes. It's likely that you have a directory somewhere with
> many very small files.
> ```

What are inodes?

> Ext4 has a theoretical limit of 4 billion files, which is restricted by the size of inode number it uses to identify each file (ext4 uses 32-bit inode numbers). However, as John says, Ext4 allocates inode tables statically, so the actual limit is set when the file system is created.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/104986/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-files-a-file-system-can-contain)