# Write to disk permissions randomly disabled

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive

Dual-booting Win10 ( barely used ) & 14.04 ( daily basis ) on a desktop computer with the following hw:

- I5 4660
- AMD 7870 GPU
- MOBO : Gigabyte H97 D3H
- Crucial MX100 256 gb SSD for the OS ( 60-70% ext4 , rest NTFS for Win10 )
- Two 3TB HDDs for storage ( one with three ext4 equally-sized partitions, second with three equally-sized partitions: two ext4 + 1 NTFS partition for Windows  )

All partitions automount on startup ( fstab properly edited for ext4 & NTFS with write permissions for everything ; also: double-checked the fstab file in case something changed... looks the same as ever ; also added permissions with `sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /media/mynewdrive` )

Issue:

Have been using this desktop since 2014 with not much issues... until the last couple weeks.

I always use the same partition to store downloaded files from all my download managers... and worked fine as it should.

Couple weeks ago i was downloading a long ( 3-4 dozens ) list of videos from Vimeo ... when the app started displaying error messages about insufficient disk space... however... there's much more than enough.

Turned out that particular partition ( ext4 by the way )  no longer had write permissions. Unmounting/mounting that partition allowed me to regain write permissions, keep downloading... however, after a while ... the same issue keeps happening.

After that first incident, each time i boot into Ubuntu it complains about being unable to mount the conflictive partition and offer me the usual options before loading the desktop.

Took the ( wrong ) lazy approach and just used a different ( ext4 ) partition for all download managers... and worked fine for a couple days... until the very same issue reproduced.

Spotted this thread here:

[Unable to write to disk but disk isn't full](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689774/unable-to-write-to-disk-but-disk-isnt-full)

... read about the inodes issue... but i don't have any particular folder with too much sub-levels or tons of small files ( i.e. pictures ) ... so still kinda lost as what could be happening.

What should i start checking ?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This read-only remount happens for a reason, and the reason can be found at `dmesg` output after it happened. I think, most likely your HDD starts failing, so you better off backup important data. Side note: Ubuntu 14.04 is ancient, consider upgrading.

Comment: So... i just should go "dmesg --level=alert,crit" & "dmesg --level=err,warn" once it's on read-only ?

Comment: Just `dmesg` without any options should be good enough.

Comment: Thought about the chance of the HDD dying... but the alternate partition i used on a different HDD behaves the same and it's a more or less recent HDD for NAS... so it feels kinda weird ( not impossible i know ) . Will start backing up data anyways . Full disclosure: it's not my computer but my brother's ; aware about 14.04's age... still.. has support until  2019 and is one of the most brilliant/stable releases i can remember... however... yes, i plan on installing Neon 18.04 when it's out

Comment: Will check tomorrow but: what should i look for ? or should i pastebin everything here ?

Comment: Well, I think you'll recognize it because there would be lines about remount, and possibly errors before them. But you can drop the output in comments through some pasting-site too, I'll look at it. Btw, I just thought: you could also try running a `fsck.ext4 /dev/sdXN` on the partition, and see if that helps *(by default it's running in interactive mode — if there are too many errors or you just lazy, consider adding `-p` or `-y`)*. I haven't seen remounts caused by filesystem-specific errors, but I assume it could be a legitimate reason too.

Comment: Okay... this is weird, I did absolutely nothing... my brother didn't do anything as well ( i know i can trust him on this ) ... the issue suddenly disappeared ( ?!? ). Retracing my steps, all i did was poke around ( dmesg, mount / unmount units ) to see how it reacted... now it's gone ( ?!? ) . Will run fsck just in case ... and since Neon is out and have to install it anyways... think i'll start backing up data as well. Thank you very much.